# how to load autoplaying video after the initial load in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, autoplay

So i have a video that is `autoPlayed` and `playsinline` in an index page, every time i visit the page on mobile, it takes a little longer than other pages and that is obviously because the other pages don't have an `autoplayed` video in them.

what i want to do is to delay the loading of the video until the page (DOM) is fully loaded, in other words i don't want to reduce the loading time by first loading only the low weight assets, then after loading DOM I want the video to load and auto play.

is this possible in `reactjs`?

[this is the web page using the video](https://www.ovanya.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useEffect` to play the video after the initial js load.

```
function MyVideoComponent() {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if(videoRef){
      videoRef.current.play();
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <video ref={videoRef} />
    </>
  );
}
```